# Colorable pin view

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mapkit, quartz-graphics

Does anyone know of any code to draw the pins we see in `MKPinAnnotationView` in a regular `UIView`?

The motivation is to remove the hundreds of different colored pin images we are currently bundling with our app to drop all over medical images (regular `UIView` backed - not `MKMapView`). All I really need is to alter the pin color programmatically .

NB: I am not talking about the callout as seen in `SMCalloutView` etc .

This is to be used outside MKMapView. They are dropped into a normal UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches to consider:

1. Ship a single pin image - say, red.  Use the Core Image `CIHueAdjust` filter to change it to other colors.
2. Ship a pin image with a white bulb, and an alpha-channel-only mask image that selects the pixels in the bulb.  Use Core Graphics to create new pin images dynamically at runtime.  You'll want to draw the white bulb pin into a bitmap context.  Then use the mask image to set the context's clipping mask.  Finally, fill the context with whatever color you want the bulb to be.